# How to implement floor(double) in AVX?

Tags: c++, c, avx, floor

The C and C++ function `double floor(double arg)` (defined in `cmath` and `math.h`) returns the largest integer value not greater than `arg`. What is the most efficient way to vectorise this using AVX instructions?

Essentially, what I want is

```
__m256d floor(__m256d arg);
```

Is it necessary to convert to integer and back?

Comment: Do you want to support values greater than 2^31?

Comment: I don't think you even could convert to integer safely, because there isn't a packed double->64bit integer conversion until AVX512, only scalar `CVTTSD2SI r64, xmm/m64`.  Good thing there's SSE4.1 `roundpd`. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That intrinsic exists as [_mm256_floor_pd](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX&text=floor&expand=2353)

Comment: Ooops. For some reason, it evaded my search.

Comment: @Walter: it happens to all of us :) The intrinsics guide I linked too is great for search though.